# Marketing cloud-Email Tracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, tracking

Is it possible to find how the email is triggered by querying the data view?
I wanted to find if the email is triggered via which campaign.

Comment: What's a "campaign" in this context?

Comment: @Macca  I have integrated Sales and MC, am not able to find the Individual Email Results in Salesforce contacts. I have 18 dig ContactID as subscriber key. Am sending emails through Automation am able to find the tracking data under My Tracking in MC but the Email Send in Salesforce don't populate.

Comment: Have you checked the boxes on the Marketing Cloud tab in Sales Cloud to enable IERs at the individual level to be pushed? How are you sending your emails in SFMC? Sending to Salesforce Data Extensions, using Journey Builder, sending to Reports/Campaigns, sending from within Sales Cloud or just doing regular sends to normal Data Extensions?

Comment: You won’t get any SC Campaign reference in Marketing Cloud tracking unless you build something specifically for that purpose beforehand

Comment: Kind of confused as there is no explanation in the Docs. How does the  tracking work on these sends. 1. Journey Send- I know there is a option to track back to salesforce 2. User-initated Send -? 3. Emails sent through automation-?. Can someone throw light on this?